# How can I use xml.sax module on an executable made with PyInstaller?

Tags: python

I want to have my application read a document using xml.sax.parse. Things work fine but when I move the executable to a Windows server 2008 machine things break down. I get an SAXReaderNotAvailable exception with "No parsers found" message.

The setup I'm using to build the executable is:

- 64 bit windows 7
- Python 2.7.2 32-bit
- PyInstaller 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable turned out to be fine. For some reason or the other there's wrong versions of the needed dlls in PATH and the executable ended up trying to use those.

Answer (score 1):

SAX readers seems to be dynamically imported, so the static analysis can't detect them and they can't be embedded with application.

To correct this, you'll have to be explicit to force PyInstaller to import those [hidden modules](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/latest/tags/1.5.1/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#listing-hidden-imports).

Try to add this to you .spec (thanks Velociraptors) file :

```
hiddenimports = ['xml.sax.drivers', 'xml.sax.drivers2']
```

Comment: I haven't run into setup.py before when using PyInstaller. I had a go looking for the file with no luck. I tried to add these to the spec file, no luck. I also checked the hook-xml.sax.py file and added these there, does not help.

Comment: Downloaded svn trunk. Found setup.py, and added these. Now the executable won't run even on my machine so I guess that's SOME progress.

Comment: @Matti Uusitalo : moving (forward or not) is a kind of progress.... Could you post the details of the traceback/errors you got in your question ?

Comment: PyInstaller doesn't use setup.py. You need to add the imports to the .spec file generated when you run MakeSpec.py on your project.

Comment: This isn't very helpful to me, but maybe you can make something out of it.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 276, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 105, in make_chart
      File "<string>", line 77, in read_sharepointlist
      File "C:\git\buildenv\overview_tw_summary\build\pyi.win32\overview_summary\
    outPYZ1.pyz/xml.sax", line 30, in parse
      File "C:\git\buildenv\overview_tw_summary\build\pyi.win32\overview_summary\outPYZ1.pyz/xml.sax", line 93, in make_parser
    xml.sax._exceptions.SAXReaderNotAvailable: No parsers found

Comment: Sorry about the messy traceback. Couldn't figure out how to make it format properly here.

Comment: Just to be sure, I already tried to add hiddenimports line to the spec file. It did not help :/